# NFS client move files in different directories at the same server

Tags: nfs

Does moving files between two folders on a single remote NFS server redirect the files through the client, or does the server simply adjust it's directory structure?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a good thread about it with good answers

http://serverfault.com/questions/547604/transfer-between-two-nfs-shares-on-the-same-machine